# How can I generate dynamic popup with html ?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a jquery popup :

```
   <div id="dialog-modal" title="Test">
    <p>Test</p>      
</div>

   $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 300,
        height: 250,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        }
    });

    $("#modal-opener").click(function () {       
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");

    });
```

And I have a html code from db. Example:

```
ViewBag.Test = "<table><tr><td>Test</td></tr><tr><td>Test 123</td></tr>";
```

So, I want this html into popup

How Can I do ?

Thank You.

Comment: Just replace `<p>Test</p>` with `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Test)`

Comment: I've tried but other html elements not load

Comment: What other elements? All your question indicates is that your want to render the value of `ViewBag.Test`

Comment: yes but,i want  only when i click render the value of `ViewBag.Test` in to popup

Comment: Why - its initially hidden!

Comment: I don't know.My container is not load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use `.html()` before open.

```
$("#modal-opener").click(function () {       
     $("#dialog-modal").html("<b>New HTML</b>");                               
     $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: @FerhatArslan : No problem, Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this:

```
$("#dialog-modal").html('<table><tr><td>Test</td></tr><tr><td>Test 123</td></tr>');
// It will append the passed html to the popup div

$("#dialog-modal").dialog({
    // this will open the popup with the appended html
});
```